# Android app works on 5.0 but not on 6.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I recently had some beta test for my app. The app works fine on Android 5.0 and even some lower deivices, but not on Android 6.0. Does anybody know what could be an issue here or how one might upgrade their app to support a newer Android OS

Some context about my app:
It uses Firebase auth and database.
Core Use case for this app is getting, sending and showing gps locations on maps.

The problem in Android 6.0 now is that the GPS is not activated when using the app

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to ask for location permission from device above marshmallow. [Android’s Runtime Permission](http://androidgig.com/androids-runtime-permission/)

Comment: You need to request **runtime permissions**. Read the Android 6 release notes

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i am going to test this

Answer (score 0):

In marshmallow GPS location access is achived by runtime permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Make sure your permissions are declared in your manifest.xml

If target sdk version is marshmallow ,we need to implement runtime permissions for GPS access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for permissions at runtime in android 6+. This is the reason why no permission is asked when you are installing your application like its asking in android lollipop. Visit android developer page to learn how to ask for permission for android M and above visit : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html